# Audio files not loading properly in Shiny App

Tags: r, audio, shiny

I am trying to load an mp3 file held in the www folder in my shiny app. After having lots of issues with this, I have just reproduced the problem in a very simple shiny App (code below).

The audio file I am using, "brand.mp3" is a 19MB mp3 file

When I run this, it returns a 500 error.  What is really weird is, if I close RStudio, and then restart, the first time I run the app, the file loads. Then if I reload, there is nothing at all. The first image shows first load of app:

[image]
And on the the reload I get this: 
[image]

The Chrome console then gives an error: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)

Code for this is below.

Would be grateful for any ideas on this one. The only thing I can think of is if the app has some kind of memory issue. I have the same problem if I running RStudio in Windows or if I am running the app through a Docker Shiny Server Image [found here](https://hub.docker.com/r/rocker/shiny/)

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(

  # App title ----
  titlePanel("Test app"),

  # Sidebar layout with input and output definitions ----
  sidebarLayout(

    # Sidebar panel for inputs ----
    sidebarPanel(

      # Input: Slider for the number of bins ----
      sliderInput(inputId = "bins",
                  label = "Number of bins:",
                  min = 1,
                  max = 50,
                  value = 30),
      tags$audio(src = "brand.mp3", type = "audio/mp3", autoplay = NA, controls = NA)

    ),

    mainPanel(
      plotOutput(outputId = "distPlot")

    )
  )
)



server <- function(input, output) {


  output$distPlot <- renderPlot({

    x    <- faithful$waiting
    bins <- seq(min(x), max(x), length.out = input$bins + 1)

    hist(x, breaks = bins, col = "#75AADB", border = "white",
         xlab = "Waiting time to next eruption (in mins)",
         main = "Histogram of waiting times")

  })

}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Just a follow up - this seems to cause no issues with smaller mp3 files (i.e ~1MB), so I am assuming the MP3 files I am working with are just too big - any suggestions around this welcome

Comment: You can change the size file Shiny will take by adding something like this to the server `options(shiny.maxRequestSize=30*1024^2)` (for 30 Mb).

Comment: Thanks Greg! I will play around with this, its definitely a file size thing as it turns out